# create an int column after dividing a column by a number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have a panda data frame with a column that holds seconds.

I want to create a new column that holds minutes. so I divide the sec column by 60. The problem that I have is that min column is not an integer anymore. How can I make it an integer?

I have this code:

```
alldata['min']=alldata['sec']/60
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
alldata['min']=int(alldata['sec']/60)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I tried this:

```
alldata["min"] = pd.to_numeric(alldata["min"], downcast='integer')
```

but I still have float values in min column.

How can have integer values for min? (Just drop the value to its floor value)

Comment: `alldata['min']=alldata['sec'] // 60`?

Comment: @HenryEcker what NaN? what about pd.NA?

Comment: `.astype('Int64')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use whole integer division:

```
alldata['min']=alldata['sec']//60
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.astype()` to convert dataframe columns to different types. In your case use the following line:

```
alldata['min']= (alldata['sec']/60).astype("int")
```

[DocPage](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alldata['min'] = alldata['min'].astype('int64')
```

or `.astype('int32')` Based on your operating system